# Element API endpoint without a resourceKey

Tags: plugin-elementapi

The output of a Element API endpoint allows you to change the resourceKey which contains the json data. Is it possible to return *just* the data without a resourceKey at all?

Values such as null, false and empty string just default to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not cleanly... the [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) library that the Element API plugin uses to serialize that data has `'data'` hard-coded as the root element if no other resource key is passed in.